# How can I delete entries from a table using pyignite?

Tags: python, ignite

I have a Apache Ignite database running which I want to interact with using Python thin client (pyignite). I've already performed create, read and update operations, but I meet problems with the delete ones. For now, even if the submission of delete request does not raise any error, the entries that are supposed to be deleted are not.

I've tried deleting those same entries running the same delete query in terminal via `jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/` and this does succesfully remove the targeted entries.

Here is how I unsuccesfully tried to delete data :

```py
self.client = Client()
self.client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10800)
patientID = 5
IS_DEFINED_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Patients WHERE PatientID = ?"
result = self.client.sql(
    IS_DEFINED_QUERY,
    query_args=[patientID]
)
try:
    next(result)
    DELETE_QUERY = "DELETE FROM Patients WHERE PatientID = ?"
    self.client.sql(
        DELETE_QUERY,
        query_args=[patientID])
except StopIteration:
            raise KeyDoesNotExist()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

EDIT: I've got some suggestions saying it might come from database settings that would prevent Thin Client from executing deletions, any thought about it ?

Comment: Can you include a full reproducer? Take a look at: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/python/examples/sql.py
Try running a DELETE query there: resultD = client.sql( "DELETE FROM City WHERE id = ?", query_args=[3802] ) -- it works.

Comment: What is the type of `PatientID`?

Comment: PatientID is a simple int

Comment: @AlexK I edited my question to expand the code context

Comment: It works in my tests. modify https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/python/examples/sql.py
to delete a city: 
id = 3802
resultD = client.sql(
    "DELETE FROM City WHERE id = ?",
    query_args=[id]
)

Comment: Well that's quite strange ... I guess the problem is elsewhere, thanks for answering